# Нужно чтобы страница оставалась на прежнем месте и не прокручивалась вверх при закрытии меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

При открытии меню задаю тегу BODY такие стили.

```
    $("body").css({
        "position" : "fixed",
        "top" :  -$(document).scrollTop() + "px",
        "overflow" : "hidden",
        "right" : 0,
        "left" : 0,
        "bottom" : 0
    });
```

Это для того чтобы меню которое ляжет поверх можно было скролить и при этом не скролилась страница. Но после закрытия страницы я делаю так

```
$("body").attr("style", "");
```

И страница сайта резко переходит на самый вверх, то есть не остается на месте и нужно опять скролить вниз.

```js
$("#show_fiters").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$(".filters").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".filters").fadeIn(300);
    $("body").css({
      "position": "fixed",
      "top": -$(document).scrollTop() + "px",
      "overflow": "hidden",
      "right": 0,
      "left": 0,
      "bottom": 0
    });
  } else {
    $(".filters").fadeOut(300);
    $("body").attr("style", "");
  }
});
```

```css
.filters {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <button type="button" id="show_fiters">Показать фильтры</button>
  </header>


  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="filters">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
  </div>

</div>
```

Нужно чтобы после закрытия меню страница оставалась на своем прежнем месте. Как это сделать?

Comment: рабочий пример покажите ...

Comment: https://postolenko.github.io/allbcsite/info_side.html                 Вот эта страница. Проскрольте и  нажмиет на " Еще фильтры " а потом еще раз  " Еще фильтры " и страница перескакнет вверх.

Comment: Уважаемый Автор вопроса ...код надо показывать здесь а не на github или ещё где попало ...Вам лень сюда скопипастить код а вот всем остальным лень лазить по всяким git_ам и искать проблему

Comment: Поправил вопрос вверху

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну может так, получить top, и просколллить на полученную величину:

```
curTop = $("body").css("top");
curTop = Math.abs(parseInt(curTop, 10));
$("body").attr("style", "")
if(curTop !==0) { 
   $("html").scrollTop(curTop);
}
```

```js
$("#show_fiters").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$(".filters").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".filters").fadeIn(300);
    $("body").css({
      "position": "fixed",
      "top": -$(document).scrollTop() + "px",
      "overflow": "hidden",
      "right": 0,
      "left": 0,
      "bottom": 0
    });
  } else {
    $(".filters").fadeOut(300);
    curTop = $("body").css("top");
    curTop = Math.abs(parseInt(curTop, 10));
    $("body").attr("style", "")
    if (curTop !== 0) {
        $("html").scrollTop(curTop);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
section {
  height: 50vh;
}

.filters {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#show_fiters {
  position: fixed;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <button type="button" id="show_fiters">Показать фильтры</button>
  </header>


  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="filters">
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
    <section>With Content</section>
  </div>

</div>
```